# Activating plugin on Appium Server2.0

Tags: appium

I'm running Appium Server 2, and some plugins show up as active, but some don't.
I would like to enable the element-wait plugin, how do I do that?
[image: Appium server running]

Comment: Where have you searched, and what have you tried? What were the results?

Comment: I tried to use the server command as another plugins:
appium server -ka 800 -pa /wd/hub --use-driver="uiautomator2" --use-plugins="images,dashboard,wait-plugin,reporter-plugin,execute-driver"
The execute-driver for example, appears as (ACTIVE)
and I tried to ask for gpt chat what I need...

Answer (score 0):

I find! the correct command to start the server:

```
appium -ka 800 -pa /wd/hub --use-driver="uiautomator2" --use-plugins="images,appium-dashboard,appium-reporter-plugin,element-wait,execute-driver, universal-xml"
```